# In flutter web application when i try to fetch excel data consisting of 7 sheets using excel package then it gives me some date time issue

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to fetch data from a particular excel file using excel package then it gives me error as:
DateTime is outside valid range: 9989518819130000

//Function to fetch excel file

```
 void pickAndProcessFile() async {
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

      if (result != null) {
        final List<int> bytes = result.files.single.bytes!;
        final excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
        var sheet1 = excel.tables.keys.elementAt(0);
        print(sheet1);
      }
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Error decoding Excel file: $e');
      print(stackTrace);

    }
  }
```

I have tried to fetch different excel data and on other excel files this function is working fine but for a specific excel with 7 sheets its not loading data

Comment: Can you check manually if there is a date incorrectly formatted on this specific Excel?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal reproducible example of an excel file that leads to this error?

Comment: Thanks! , enzo i have checked whole excel file and in a sheet there are some date format issues.